# Packet sequence number wrong - got 7 expected 2 celery+flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: multithreading, sqlalchemy, celery

I am using flask to write web pages and celery for asynchronous tasks. In Celery, I used sqlalchemy's ORM model to do database queries. But when the amount of data query is large, various errors will be reported.

```
Packet sequence number wrong - got 7 expected 2
pymysql.err.OperationalError:(2014, "Command Out of Sync")
MySQL server has gone away(BrokenPipeError 32, broken pipe)
can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back
```

I guess it may be caused by multiple threads sharing a database connection. However, it is difficult for me to create multiple database connections in a celery task. How can I solve this problem?

in celery:

```
from app.db import db
@celery.task
def taskA():
    db.session.query(Models).filter() # large query
```